# Prefill checkbox in symfony

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony4

I have a user entity, with a field `isSubscribed`.

I want to show the status of this (boolean) as a checked or unchecked checkbox in a form.

Normally I would get this value in my formtype from a query but that seems overkill.

I want to do something like this:

```
$builder
        ->add('isSubscribed', CheckboxType::class, [
            'label'    => 'Subscribe to weekly update',
            'attr' => array('checked' => function(User $user){
                return $user->getIsSubscribed();
            }),
            'required' => false,
        ])
    ;
```

But I get an error:

> Closure could not be converted to string

Here's my formtype:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class AccountFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('isSubscribed', CheckboxType::class, [
                'label'    => 'Subscribe to weekly update',
                'required' => false,
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

In my User entity:

```
/**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $isSubscribed;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your form has a `data_class` linked to your User, the value will be set automatically.

Otherwise, you can do something like this

```php
->add('isSubscribed', CheckboxType::class, [
    'label'    => 'Subscribe to weekly update',
    'data' => $user->getIsSubscribed(),
    'required' => false,
])
```

where `$user` can be passed through [form options](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#passing-options-to-forms) if you don't have it

Comment: It is linked with a data class to the User entity. but no change. I updated the code

Comment: Are you sure you are passing your user to the form when you call `$this->createForm()` in your controller ?

Comment: That was it! Cant believe i forgot that. thanx!